# Facebook Like / Recommend button doesn't show correct link to like or image

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-like

I have added Facebook Like code (HTML5 option) to product listing pages on my website.  However, when a product is "liked" it shows up on the users timeline as them liking the homepage not the product page and also selects a random image from the homepage and not the product image from the product page.

I have the below code on my product listing pages under the body tag as instructed by Facebook:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=122370783453655";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I have this code repeated underneath each products listed on the page.  The variable $productURL will be a unique URL for each product.

```
<div class="fb-like" style="margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto" data-href="'. $productURL . '" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="50" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend"></div>
```

I have also added the below code to the $productUrl pages:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?=$image?>" />
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="<?=$simage?>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?=$title?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?=$desc?>" />
<meta property="og:url" content="<?=$url?>"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?=$sitename?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="Website"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the appid from the following line and it worked.

```
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=122370783453655";
```

For some reason when I was trying to get the code it made me select an app and then appended the app ID to the code.

All works now.

Answer (score 0):

$productURL page should contain [open graph markup](http://ogp.me/)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that it does.  I will add an example of the code above.

Comment: OK, just noticed that even though $productURL is correct, the og:url is set to the homepage.  Could this be causing it? If so, why does it still select a random image as opposed to the one set in og:image?

Answer (score 0):

`og:url` must be your product url. Facebook uses this url for posting updates on the Object..
Goto your `App page.. ->OpenGraph->Types->Browse Objects`--> Make sure your object is mapped to the right og:image. You can preview the image there.

Hope this helps.. reply if you need anything else..:)

Comment: thanks for your response, however, I don't understand why an App page has anything to do with it and am a bit confused by this.  I don't see anything about this mentioned in the instruction on the below page: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: I got confused with you using,'Objects and Actions' in 'OpenGraph' cause you were using og:type. Since you are not using any 'Open Graph' objects you dont need that tag. See the valid attributes to be used in this @ the same link you shared.

Comment: OK, Ive changed the og:url from the main web page to the product page URL and it makes no difference.  It doesn't seem to pick up any of the og meta data

Comment: Does that page contains the same meta tags. Post your url in this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and see if any error occurs. that should give you an idea.

Comment: That's a very useful tool, thanks. Its showing as all being correct when I add the URL to the page I want to like.  So all the OG Meta data is correct, it must be the HTML5 code thats displaying the like button, but what?  :0(